# Unable to load the service index for source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json

Tags: .net, visual-studio, nuget

I use Visual Studio 2019 and I program in .NET C #

So far everything has worked out great for me! But when I tried to learn something new in RAZOR PAGE I could not do CRUD.

After reading one of the answers, I deleted the entire .NUGET IN C: / users folder

I do not remember what the first error message was but I am currently stuck with an error message:

> [Package source] Unable to load the service index for source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json.
> An error occurred while sending the request.
> The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.
> Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these suggestions:

**1)** close VS, delete the whole `nuget.config` file under `C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\NuGet` and then restart VS to re-generate it. Then, try to install nuget packages again.

**2)** open powershell as **Administrator**, run these:

```
reg add "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.2\Client" /v DisabledByDefault /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f /reg:32
reg add "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.2\Client" /v DisabledByDefault /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f /reg:64
reg add "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.2\Client" /v Enabled /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f /reg:32
reg add "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.2\Client" /v Enabled /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f /reg:64
```

Restart VS to test again.

Comment: Maybe you should abandon `http://packages.nuget.org/v1/FeedService.svc/ `. Try the two steps and then when you install the nuget package, do not forget to choose the `nuget.org` source